# How I can monitor database connectivity in real-time? GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-monitoring

I need to monitor connectivity to SQL instance from the vpc network(at least) in real-time.

I can do it with Connectivity tests, but the Connectivity test runs only when created one time, and then I need to re-run manually or with cloud-function, it`s not a good solution. I need to monitor this connectivity in real-time, moreover, I need to set up alerts, when connectivity is broken.

Comment: What's the purpose of that? You shoud want to monitor is a system (VM, Serverless, something else) is connected to the SQL instance, not to have your SQL instance up. It's meaningless.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere When we make changes to our infrastructure we may have problems with connectivity to the database from, for example, vpc network, so I want to monitor this connectivity